# Javascript filter objects in in array

Tags: javascript, filter

I have this challenge, where I want to return an array with objects, where the  control array has value in the "value" property in its child object.

Besides that, it should also remove objects in control array, where there is no value

```
const data = [
      {
        'groupName': '1',
        'controls': [
          {'value': ''},
          {'value': ''}
        ]
      },
      {
        'groupName': '2',
        'controls': [
          {'value': ''},
          {'value': '2'}
        ]
      }
    ];

    const result = data.filter(cl => {
      return cl.controls.some(r => {
        return r.value !== '';
      });
    });

    console.log(result);
```

The result is this

```
[
  {
    'groupName': '2',
    'controls': [
      {'value': ''},
      {'value': '2'}
    ]
  }
];
```

but I want it to be this

```
   [
      {
        'groupName': '2',
        'controls': [
          {'value': '2'}
        ]
      }
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested `filter()` instead of `some()`

```js
const data = [{groupName:"1",controls:[{value:""},{value:""}]},{groupName:"2",controls:[{value:""},{value:"2"}]}];;

const result = data.filter(cl => {
  cl.controls = cl.controls.filter(r => {
    return r.value !== '';
  });
  return cl.controls.length
});

console.log(result);
```

**Note:** It mutates the original array. You can use `Array.from(data).filter(...)` to avoid it